# Convert char to number if numeric or else null in Oracle

Tags: oracle, type-conversion

I would like to convert a character (I know it will always be `char(1)`) if the character is numeric ([0-9]) and return null if it is not numeric.  IOW, I would like to catch the exception and return NULL for all non-convertible characters (those outside the 0-9 range).  Is there a way to do that?  I tried using [`TO_NUMBER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm#i79512) but that fails if any of the rows have a non-numeric character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use regexp:

```
select case when regexp_like(your_string, '^[[:digit:]]+$') then to_number(your_string) else NULL end
from (select '1d23' your_string from dual);
```

For char(1)

```
select case when ascii(c) between 48 and 57 then to_number(c) else null end 
from (select '3' c from dual);
```

48 is ASCII code for '0' and 57 is ASCII code for '9', **ascii** function return ASCII code of the argument